# Compare the values of two listboxes and add the non-equivalent values to a third listbox

Tags: vb.net, listbox

My knowledge of programming is not too extensive but I have just finished my second year of higher education in computer engineering and have taken a few low level programming courses.

In Visual Basic, I am having trouble comparing the values of two `ListBox` controls and putting the values that aren't the same into another `ListBox`.

I need to compare the items of `ListBox2` to the items of `ListBox1` and if there are any items in `ListBox2` that are not in `ListBox1`, add them to `ListBox3`. I do not need to find the items in `ListBox1` that are not in `ListBox2`. I cannot use a loop to compare their values based on index because these lists are of names which will be constantly added to and removed from. I also cannot sort these ListBoxes.

There was an example for C# that I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22125305/comparing-two-list-box-and-displaying-the-differences-vb-net) that used LINQ (I don't really know what that is) to compare the lists and then add the result to a `TextBox` control. However, I need to know how to add them to a `ListBox` and not a `TextBox`.

[EDIT] The example that I have tried is this:

```
Dim result As List(Of String) = (From s1 As String In Me.ListBox1.Items Where Not Me.ListBox2.Items.Contains(s1) Select s1).ToList()
Me.TextBox1.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, result)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please show us [what you have tried](//whathaveyoutried.com), as well as the specific problem or error that you are encountering. Be sure to include a [Minimum, Complete, Verifiable Example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated. I tried using the first answer to the question that I hyperlinked in my question but that uses a textbox and it does work. However, I'm not sure how to add each item to the items collection of the listbox without typing out each listbox.items.add line which would indicate that I know how big each listbox is going to be and I don't know how big each could be. Also, so far I just tried that one example to see if it would work. This is the link to the example. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22125305/comparing-two-list-box-and-displaying-the-differences-vb-net

Comment: If you can't sort, and you don't have an ID field, you could loop the list boxes.  Compare each entry in LB2 to the entries in LB1 if it doesn't exist add that record to LB3.  This will be slow and is very prone to error.  If the data comes from a DB it would be more efficient to run the check there and populate all three LBs at the same time.

Comment: @MaCron You would think that this is being done in a database because it should be but its being done in an excel file and I'm reading the names from different files and writing them to certain cells. I know this is a poor method but I'm waiting for an SQL book to arrive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    Dim one As ListBox = New ListBox()
    Dim two As ListBox = New ListBox()
    Dim three As ListBox = New ListBox()
    Dim unique As Boolean = True

    For i As Integer = 0 To one.Items.Count
        For j As Integer = 0 To two.Items.Count
            If (one.Text = two.Text) Then
                unique = False
            Else
                two.SelectedIndex = j
            End If
        Next
        If (unique) Then
            three.Items.Add(one.Text)
        Else
            one.SelectedIndex = i
            unique = True
        End If
    Next
```

I believe this may be what you're looking for. What it does is compares each value in `Listbox one` to all values in `Listbox two` and if a value is seen to be a duplicate the `Boolean` flag `unique` is switched to false and the item is not added to `Listbox three`.

Comment: This is the first time I'm seeing a Boolean unique but it is what I'm looking for. Thank you very much for taking your time to answer my question =)

Comment: Well it is just a Boolean value that I have named unique. It is used as a flag to determine whether a duplicate value was found.                             I'm glad this was your solution, if you could click the check mark to approve this solution it would help me very much. Thank you. :)

Comment: Oh haha wow I read that too quick and missed it. I wish I could give both the check marks because both are good answers

Answer (score 0):

I think i found the solution:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    ListBox3.Items.Clear()
    Dim result As List(Of String) = (From s1 As String In Me.ListBox2.Items Where Not Me.ListBox1.Items.Contains(s1) Select s1).ToList()
    For Each l In result
        ListBox3.Items.Add(l)
    Next
End Sub
```

or

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim result As List(Of String) = (From s1 As String In Me.ListBox2.Items Where Not Me.ListBox1.Items.Contains(s1) Select s1).ToList()
    For Each l In result
        If Not ListBox3.Items.Contains(l) Then
            ListBox3.Items.Add(l)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Try which works best for you :)

Comment: The second way you describe is the way that I need to compare these items. The first item from listbox1 to all items from listbox2, the second item from listbox1 to all items from listbox2 e.t.c

Comment: (@BanForFun) Welcome to Stack Overflow! This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. If you [earn](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/146472/169503) sufficient [reputation](//stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](//stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Sorry it didn't let me post a comment

Comment: @BanForFun Wow this was such a simple change to the example. I feel dumb now but thank you very much for your answer.